# How to parse TFL api

Tags: android

I am currently working on TFL based projects. And i want to parse the json file which is available in this link : http://countdown.api.tfl.gov.uk/interfaces/ura/instant_V1
So please help me out

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This API is not standard *JSON* as written in the *TFL* API documentation. It us actually best parsed as CSV but watch out because I have found out that some responses are inconsistent where the first line might have 6 strings while the second might have 5 with the missing field not identified as an empty string but simply omitted. This way parsing with a CSV parser will lead to errors since you might never know what is omitted.

I have also searched for the solution and the best I could find was another API that gives standard JSON but  only returns bus stop countdown via a `stopCode` request.

Use This Link To Access It. 
**http://countdown.tfl.gov.uk/stopBoard/75288**

Im suprised as to why TFL uses this api for their own apps but not implement the public api to return good JSon like this one.

Comment: A link perhaps? To the API you found.

Comment: Updated Answer See My Comment

Comment: You should not use a CSV parser as it is not a CSV. See my answer on how to parse it on a line by line basis.

Answer (score 0):

This API is not standard JSON as written in the TFL API documentation.so after get the content  you may change that format. Use this link http://jsonlint.com/ it will validate your json format. so you can easily understand json format error

After get the content do this

```
 JSONArray jArray = new JSONArray("["+ result.replaceAll("]", "],").toString() + "]")
```

now you get proper json array skip jArray 0th position this is - URA Version array.

Comment: Bette r yet use some CSV parse that would enable you access the fiels as objects. But this is still inconsistent because the fields are not properly populated as i have discovered. For example a request that should return 7 field on each line sometimes returns 5 or 6 on some lines. Because the missing fields are not identified as empty strings the parser would never know what field is missing.

Answer (score 0):

It is not a single full JSON object, as per the TFL documentation. You treat each line as a separate JSON object. This way if/when you move to the streaming mode, you can continue to receive objects and interpreting them as they get streamed to you. Also you use the first element in the JSON array to determine how to process that particular line, or in some cases if you need to refresh the base data.